# Highlight/trigger click event for div

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I am binding records to div in following way

```
<div class="well" id="divQuestionList">
<div class="jarviswidget">
    @if ((ViewBag.classDiscussion as List<LMS_ClassDiscussionListViewModel>).Count > 0)
    {
        @foreach (var item in ViewBag.classDiscussion as List<LMS_ClassDiscussionListViewModel>)
        {
            <div id="divQuestion_@item.ClassDiscussion.ClassDiscussionID" class="fc-content" onclick="GetDiscussionDetails(@item.ClassDiscussion.ClassDiscussionID);" data-divtoggle="0" role="button">
                <b>@item.ClassDiscussion.DiscussionTitle</b>
                <div class="unsortable widget-toolbar hidden-phone">
                    <div class="unsortable divider dark">
                        <label id="lblReply_@item.ClassDiscussion.ClassDiscussionID">@item.ReplyCount @objLocalizer["ClassDiscussionResponses"]</label>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="divContent_@item.ClassDiscussion.ClassDiscussionID" style="display:none;">
                <div class="chat-body no-padding profile-message">
                    <ul id="ulContainer_@item.ClassDiscussion.ClassDiscussionID"></ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    }
```

and in controller I have ID of div stored in session for which click event needs to be triggered OR need to be highlighted.

So, my question is how can I trigger the click the click event for the related div ?

I have tried in document.Ready function, but it triggers the event each time the page is refreshed. I just want to trigger the event for first time/only for once.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
          $('#divQuestion_1').trigger('click');

    });
</script>
```

So, which is best possible way to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i hope your answer here.  **see** this fiddle `trigger` call. and function can be execute.

**Notes:** replace id to `id="divQuestion_@item.ClassDiscussion.ClassDiscussionID"` **To** `id="divQuestion_1"` because i execute html and i create demo for you . trigger are worked and function are call..

**Live Demo** **<kbd>[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/patelsumit5192/fa0v0njt/)</kbd>**

**Snippet Example**

```js
 function GetDiscussionDetails() {
   alert(' GetDiscussionDetails Function is call');
 }
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('#divQuestion_1').trigger('click');

 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="well" id="divQuestionList">
  <div class="jarviswidget">

    <div id="divQuestion_1" class="fc-content" onclick="GetDiscussionDetails()" data-divtoggle="0" role="button">
      <b>@item.ClassDiscussion.DiscussionTitle</b>
      <div class="unsortable widget-toolbar hidden-phone">
        <div class="unsortable divider dark">
          <label id="lblReply_@item.ClassDiscussion.ClassDiscussionID">@item.ReplyCount @objLocalizer["ClassDiscussionResponses"]</label>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="divContent_2" style="display:none;">
      <div class="chat-body no-padding profile-message">
        <ul id="ulContainer_@item.ClassDiscussion.ClassDiscussionID"></ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, I have done in same way, but on which condition do I need to trigger the event and if page is refreshed then the trigger will be called again if written in document. Ready, which I dont want

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Delegate for genearting click event of div Tag. like: $('body').delegates('#divQuestionList','click',function(){ // write your code  });

Comment: When this will be triggered ? After finishing of my for loop ??

Comment: When you click on div tag .it will work like normal button click event.

Comment: And when records are populated to div the event will be triggered automatically ?

Comment: after loading complete layout .div tag work like button.(means : all content load automatically )

Comment: And if I refreshed the page then this should not trigger the event ?

Comment: why are you going to refreshed the page . i think you need to update the content of  div tag divQuestionList (if i am write the ) then use below code :('body').delegates('#divQuestionList','click',function(){ GetDiscussionDetails(@item.ClassDiscussion.ClassDiscussionID); });

Comment: By mistake user refreshed the page

Comment: this is user mistake not your code.So page is working normal process as always when url is call every time